# Split string to array and perform specific action for each character Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have string, something like `(495)_-___-____`. That is mask for telephone number. I have libray named [InputMask](https://cocoapods.org/pods/InputMask)

That library have specific rules to form a mask for text field. So, i need to somethow transform above mask to `{495[0]_[0][0][0]_[0][0][0]`, that would be correct format.

So, i wonder if i may achieve that point with functions like map? I simply need to break string `(495)_-___-____` to array of characters. If that character is equal to "_" or "*" that is place when user will put on characters on text field, so i simple replace it with [0]. Other characters is symbol should left untouched.

How to perform this splitting string to Array and form a new array using map function?

Comment: you can just make an new string while iterating over this string on its characters. As you encounter a character, you can apply your rule

Comment: Are you sure there is an unbalanced `{` at the start?

Comment: Infact, if the positions of `_` is constant, you may just perform mask over the position.

Comment: @Sweeper { is ok.

Comment: @prabodhprakash yes but i asking if i could do that with map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
let mask = "(495)_-___-____"
// use mask.map in swift 4
let strings: [String] = mask.characters.map {
    char in
    if char == "_" {
        return "[0]"
    } else if char == "-" {
        return "_"
    } else {
        return char.description
    }
}


let finalResult = "{" + strings.joined()
```

As you can see, the code is pretty straightforward. The code inside the `map` closure is quite long, so a loop would probably look nicer (IMO).

Here is another solution not using high-order functions, but IMO is simpler:

```
"{" + mask.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "[0]")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "_")
```

Comment: Agreed that, if solving by `map` is not an absolute criteria to solve the problem, solving it using simple `for` loop would make more sense.

Comment: @prabodhprakash yes i agree but i guess i can make it simplier and cleaner by use map

Comment: @Sweeper thanks it work but i still want solution with high order functions, because if you master it, that would save your time and will be less code.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban I don't think there is a simpler way with `map`. But as you can see in my edit, you can use 2 `replaceOccurrence` calls.